# Constrains causing black spots on display

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, autolayout, storyboard, nslayoutconstraint

I am pretty new to styling/Constraints/Auto-Layout in iOS. I am having a problem that when I apply constrains to one of my ViewControllers I get black "bars" around the edges.

## Here is what it looks like in the story board:

[image]

## Here is what it looks like on the phone:

---

[image]

## Question

How do I fix this?

## Edit

I know this is an issue with constrains because when I don't use constraints it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Sure things, Thank you so much! https://github.com/pudility/quick-things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `[self.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO]` in your `DateModificationViewController`